# What was the initial velocity in the y direction $v_x = 3.6 \text{ m/s} \times \cos 18°$?

Tags: trigonometry, physics, kinematics

A ball is thrown, it's path is oblique; it's velocity is depicted by the $x$-axis formula $v_x = 3.6 \text{ m/s} \times \cos 18°$. What was the initial velocity in the $y$ direction?

I have no idea how to calculate the answer?

Comment: If the initial angle is $\theta$ and velocity is $v,v_x=v\cdot\cos\theta \implies v\cdot\cos\theta=3.6\cdot\cos18^\circ \implies \theta=18^\circ$ and $v_y=v\sin\theta$

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you mean with "oblique".
 In any case, if your initial velocity vector has length $v$, then you are asking for the length of the component parallel to the y-axis, i.e. $v_y$, with $v_x$ given. 
As $v_x=v \cos 18°$ and $v_y=v \sin 18°$, then using $v=3.6\text{ m/s}$ you find $v_y=3.6*\sin 18°\text{ m/s}$.

Comment: Oblique or crooked

Comment: ok, then the ball is thrown in a direction which is not parallel to the x-axis (as the angle with the positive x-axis is $18°$). Does my answer help you?

Comment: then you could upvote the answer :-)